# argmin parameter and text below it

Tags: microsoft-word, equations

I am trying to write the equation shown below in a Microsoft Word document:
[image: equation]
I have tried to write something like this:
[image: attempt]
but when I export the Word doc as a pdf I don't get the same results as the first picture (the equation in the pdf doc looks like the second image). I have seen other posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068852/how-do-you-put-text-below-other-text/1069159#1069159) for example, but either I am doing something wrong or the solution is not relevant to my problem.

How can I write the equation of the first image in the Word document?

Comment: I edited the question and I added how the output pdf look like. As for the _argmin_ I'd like to be like in the 1st image in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is the closest I can get using the Cambria Math font.

Create a new equation.

With Unicode () not LateX selected...

Either insert the f with hat using insert->Symbol, or e.g. on Windows type 0125 then press Alt-X, or using your preferred method.

Then type the following, where `<space>` means "press the spacebar"

```
_C^l=\begin<space>argmin\end<space>\below(h_C^l)<space>\zwsp<space>f(<space>\sum_k<space>(\alpha_k<space>(Z_F^k*h_C^l)
```

then press the right arrow key to move beyond the box containing the summation operand.

Finally, type

```
)<space>
```

The zero-width space inserted using \zwsp may appear as a "box" character unless you hide it, e.g. using the show/hide button in the Home tab of the ribbon. I also had to select each Z character and apply bold to it - not sure how to get the formatting you have, which seems a little different.

The superscript "l" immediately after the hat-f character at the beginning is not raised as high as your image depits. I think it can be done if necessary. Also, the large () could probably be stretched a bit more vertically if necessary.

As it stands, it seems to export to PDF OK.